# Nivo Lightbox broken on iOS 7 Devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ios7, mobile-safari, nivo-slider

I'm trying to use Nivo 1.1 with jQuery 1.10.1. Works great on Desktop browsers, but is failing me on iOS 7 devices, iPad Mini and iPhone 5c. I've seen the -webkit-transition fix posted on GitHub but that fix does not work. Also, as claimed by the site, 1.1 does not seem to fix iOS issues.

I tested their demo site on both iOS devices I have and most of their lightbox links don't work either. I also get no errors when using safari developer tools to debug my iOS safari instances.

[Nivo Demo Site](http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/)

I'm specifically trying to get two YouTube videos working on mobile devices.

See example I've put together here:

[Example Page with Nivo 1.1 Lightbox + YouTube](http://brantwellons.com/nivoExample)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 164 and 168 (`nivo-lightbox.js`) where the source url for youtube is created change:

```
# 164
src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ video[4];
# 168
src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ video[3];
```

To:

```
# 164
src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ video[4] +'?autoplay=1';
# 168
src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ video[3] +'?autoplay=1';
```

This works for me, tested on iOS7 Safari, iOS7 Chrome and OSX 10.9 Chrome.

I think it's because the YouTube iOS7 app wants to take control over the video but somehow can't..

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Sorry it took a second to get back at yah, thought the question was dead at this point! Just fixed it, stellar find sir!

Comment: I tried this solution, it works on computers but on mobiles (android 6.0 nexu6, android 5.0.1 htc1) it doesn't, am I doing something wrong?